# Função JavaScript para retornar 3 valores separados

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

No código **visualizar.php** eu faço o select no **BD** e concateno uma **Table** com o resultado do select e armazeno em uma variável **$resultado**. Essa variável é lida pelo JavaScript e escrita no .

Eu gostaria de alterar o código para que o layout da Table não ficasse na variável $resultado e sim no **body do modal**. Dessa forma eu preciso que o JavaScript escreva no modal os valores separados.

Algo assim:

```js
$("#grid-tipo").html(id_tipo);
$("#grid-tipo").html(tipo);
$("#grid-tipo").html(status);
```

Tentei usar um vetor mas não obtive sucesso.

**visualizar.php**

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST["id_tipo"])){
 include_once "conexao.php";
 $resultado = '';
 $query_user = "SELECT * FROM tipos WHERE id_tipo = '" . $_POST["id_tipo"] . "' LIMIT 1";
 $resultado_user = mysqli_query($conn, $query_user);
 $row_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_user);
 $resultado .= '<dl class="row">';
 $resultado .= '<dt class="col-sm-3">Código</dt>';
 $resultado .= '<dd class="col-sm-9">'.$row_user['id_tipo'].'</dd>';
 $resultado .= '<dt class="col-sm-3">Tipo</dt>';
 $resultado .= '<dd class="col-sm-9">'.$row_user['tipo'].'</dd>';
 $resultado .= '<dt class="col-sm-3">Status</dt>';
 $resultado .= '<dd class="col-sm-9">'.$row_user['status'].'</dd>';
 $resultado .= '</dl>';
 echo $resultado;
}
?>
```

**javascrip que transporta os valores**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function () {
        var id_tipo = $(this).attr("id");
        if (id_tipo !== '') {
            var dados = {
                id_tipo : id_tipo
            };
            $.post('visualizar.php', dados, function (retorna) {
                $("#grid-tipo").html(retorna);
                $('#viewParamTipos').modal('show');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**código do modal que recebe os valores**

```html
<div id="viewParamTipos" class="modal fade"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="viewParamTipos" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Visualização de Tipos de Veículos</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
   </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <span id="grid-tipo"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
   </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é o seguinte, no seu PHP (visualizar.php), ao invés de retornar uma string com a tabela, retornar uma string com os valores separados por vírgula. Exemplo:

```
$resultado="codigo,tipo,status";
echo $resultado;
```

Na página onde está o modal, criar uma função para ser executada quando o modal for aberto (show)

```
var retorno = ['','', ''];
$('#viewParamTipos').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) { 
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('#id').html(retorno[0]);
    modal.find('#tipo').html(retorno[1]);
    modal.find('#status').html(retorno[1]);
});
```

Perceba que o array "retorno" foi criado com um conteúdo vazio.

Para atualizar o conteúdo dele antes de exibir o modal, você vai precisar fazer o seguinte ajuste na hora de ler o retorno da sua página php (click no botão com a class "'.view_data")

```
$.post('visualizar.php', dados, function (retorna) {
    retorno = retorna.split(','); //Converte a string em array
    $('#viewParamTipos').modal('show');
});
```

Aqui tem mais algumas informações:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp